# Is there a relationship between καθαιρέω ("destroy") and καθαίρω ("purify")?

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek, word-comparison

[καθαιρέω](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%81%CE%AD%CF%89) and [καθαίρω](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%B1%CE%AF%CF%81%CF%89) look remarkably similar and seem to have similar meanings: "destroy" and "purify/purge," respectively.

It came as some surprise to me, though, that I couldn't find an obvious relationship between the two.

- **καθαιρέω** obviously comes from κατα- +‎ [αἱρέω](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B1%E1%BC%B1%CF%81%CE%AD%CF%89) ("seize," "take away"). [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%E1%BC%B1%CF%81%CE%AD%CF%89) lists a pretty straightforward etymology from PIE:

  > From Proto-Hellenic *həřřéyō, from Proto-Indo-European *ser- (“to take, grasp”).
- **καθαίρω**, on the other hand, seems to come from the *adjective* καθαρός ("pure"), about whose etymology [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) is much less certain:

  > No Indo-European cognates can be drawn. This implies a borrowing from Pre-Greek.

**Is it just a strange accident that these two words are so similar in spelling (and, to a certain extent, meaning)? Is there really no relationship (even if only in the prefix καθ-) between them?**

Comment: (This question is partly inspired by [an answer I saw on the Biblical Hermeneutics site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/92836/prunes-or-cleanses-in-john-151-4-esv/92845#92845) arguing about the meaning of one verb based on the other's.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You and Wiktionary are correct: they're unrelated. The big tell is that καθ- is not a prefix, and the Doric and Aeolic forms have an omicron there instead of an alpha, which isn't something you would have seen with κατα-.

Here is what Beekes says:

> ETYM No etymology, see Frisk and DELG for unsuccessful older attempts. The
> variation α/ο points to Pre-Greek origin (Fur.: 391 even connects it with ἀθαρής, but this is doubtful). Alternatively, Peters 1993b: 95ff. takes up the old connection with Skt. *śithirá-* 'loose', reconstructing **kr̥th<sub>2</sub>-ro-*, but this etymology needs too many ad hoc assumptions: independent dissimilatory loss of the first *r* in both branches, doubtful laryngeal aspiration **tH* > θ (πλατύς is a strong counterexample, and cannot be explained away by πλαταμών), and too complicated semantics.

Either Pre-Greek or connected to Sanskrit, what's clear is that κατα- is not the prefix for καθαίρω/καθαρός, and thus the words look a lot less similar when you're comparing καθαίρω/καθαρός with αἰρέω alone.